# Server Error Can't Resolve System.Web.Mvc Components

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a ASP.NET MVC project on my local machine target .NET 4.0 and it works perfectly. Always has. I've been deploying this app to my production server with no problems for a very long time as well. Now all of a sudden, despite the fact I can build it on my machine, when building it in the production machine I get over 100 errors, all missing references:

> The type or namespace name 'HttpPost' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

All of these missing references are from the System.Web.Mvc dll. I just can't figure out why all of a sudden it's not working. I've tried setting the dll to copy local to no avail. Is there anything I may be missing that is causing this mvc reference not to work?

Comment: system.web.mvc upgraded to 4.0.0.1. remove system.web.mvc from references and add again

Answer (score 0):

You're probably referencing the System.Web.Mvc **version dll** 4.0 instead of **4.5**. Check the reference to that, and if it's wrong, remove it and re-add the correct version

go to setting of System.Web.Mvc reference to True (Copy Local = True)

Copy local is important for deployment scenarios and tools. As a general rule you should use CopyLocal=True if the reference is not contained within the GAC.

Copy Local essentially means you must manually deploy this DLL in order for my application to work. When it's false it essentially means "you depend on another component which must be installed separately or chained, the DLL will just be there already".

[To set the Copy Local property to True or False](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c(v=vs.90).aspx)